# Renaming multiples files with only a part of the original file name

Tags: windows-7, command-line, rename

I want to rename 40 png files in one folder, they have very long names.  They are named serially like this, "blah...blah...blah160.png", "blah...blah...blah200.png" i.e. after 40 alphanumeric characters comes the serial number in three digits (160), I want only the last three digits to remain in the file name, so, "blah...blah...blah160.png" should become "160.png", is there a simple one line DOS (cmd.exe) command in win 7?

Comment: Are there always exactly 40 characters before the number? Is the number always n digits long? Are there always spaces before the number? Can you be more specific about the file names?

Comment: @WernerHenze,yes, always 40  characters (lower case alphabets and special characters = &) before the three digit number and no spaces anywhere so it is always 43 char long file name also the beginning 40 char are always the same for all 40 file names what differs is the last three digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following cmd file should do the job:

```
@echo off & setlocal

for %%F in (*.png) do call :doIt %%F
goto xit

:doIt
set name=%~n1
set num=%name:~-3%
set ext=%~x1
set lentest=%name:~40,3%

if not [%lentest%]==[] (
  copy "%1" %num%%ext%
::  del "%1"  
)
goto :EOF

:xit
endlocal
```

Uncomment the "del" line to actually delete the version with the long name.

It is possible to squeeze this in fewer lines, but this would make it less comprehensible.